# SpringBoot - How do I create a request which can be based on user input and is then picked up by a controller method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

I have managed to send a parameterised request based on the URL entered by the user, however I am not sure how to get the 2nd controller to properly receive the route for the URL field of the Project class object. How do I do this? I don't even know what to search.

```
    //ProjectController

//Creating Project Object
            Project project = new Project();
            System.out.println("userID: " + userID);

            //Getting values using webuser userid (Parameter that passed by model attribute)
            WebUser webUser = webUserRepo.findUserById(Long.parseLong(userID));

            //Setting values to project object to save
            project.setUserID(webUser);
            project.setDescription(description);
            project.setTargets(targets);
            project.setUrl(url);

            // Getting date
            Date date = new Date();
            project.setPublishedOn(date);

            //Save Project Object and get that saved Object for system.print
            Project savedProject = projectRepo.save(project);

            //Print saved Object
            System.out.println("saved Project Object : "+ savedProject.toString());

            //Set user id in model attribute for return page
            model.addAttribute("userID", userID);
            model.addAttribute("url", url);
            return "/project-dashboard/" + savedProject.getUrl();
            
//Dashboard Controller:
    
    @GetMapping("project/{url}")
    public String serveProject(@PathVariable("url") String url, @RequestParam Long userID, Model model){



        System.out.println("OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO  ADKLLDAL " + userID);
        Project project = projectRepo.getById(userID);

        System.out.println(project.toString());


        model.addAttribute(project);
        return "project";

    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi @Joedev2, Just confirm, you want to achieve a call for two-controller in a single request.

Comment: @Sathiyaraj The first controller needs to create an URL from Project.url and send that request and the 2nd controller must receive that request. Ideally for the 2nd controller I would do @GetMapping("project/savedProject.getUrl();") but that won't work.